# Difference in thread name between local machine and server

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

We have a Spring application using Webclient that make some call to an external API.
In local environment thread names in the log are [reactor-http-nio-X] :

```
2021-12-01 15:58:42.960 |  | DEBUG 37528 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/webjars/**', method=null}
2021-12-01 15:58:42.960 |  | DEBUG 37528 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /courses' doesn't match 'null /webjars/**'
```

In the server thread names are instead [reactor-http-epoll-X] :

```
2021-12-01 15:58:34.462 |  | DEBUG 37528 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler          : [id: 0x94714fe1, L:/192.168.0.7:60057 - ...
2021-12-01 15:58:34.463 |  |  INFO 37528 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] HTTP-TRACING                             : [id:94714fe1, L:/192.168.0.7:60057 - ...
```

In my understanding this difference is also creating a different behaviour on scheduler hooks.

How can I understand why the thread names (and behaviour) are so different and how to configure the server to behave like the local machine using nio threads?

Comment: `In my understanding this difference is also creating a different behaviour on scheduler hooks` what do you mean? link a source please for this statement. Also, in your question, the linked logs contain the same thread name `ctor-http-nio-4` and `ctor-http-nio-5`

Answer (score 1):

these names reflect the fact that the underlying Netty library used on your server is the native one (Linux epoll), while your local machine is either a Mac or a Windows PC. the names should have no impact of the behavior of reactor-provided hooks, unless *you* have written hooks that specifically look at thread names...

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'm using this hook

`Schedulers.onScheduleHook("mdc", runnable -> {`

but seems not triggered in the server (Linux epoll)

Comment: are you looking at the name of the thread in the hook? you have only shared up to the opening bracket of the lambda, which doesn't help...